# count com LEFT JOIN não retorna quando zero ou null

Tags: mysql

Estou com problema em um select onde preciso pegar os dados de 3 tabelas (pesquisa, usuarios, e resposta_pesquisa). Onde resposta_pesquisa pode ou n ter dados. A query atual é:

```
SELECT 
usuarios.nome AS nome_autor,
pc_pesquisa.*,
COUNT(pc_resposta_pesquisa.id) AS respostas 
FROM pc_pesquisa
    LEFT JOIN usuarios
        ON usuarios.id = pc_pesquisa.id_autor
    LEFT JOIN pc_resposta_pesquisa
        ON pc_resposta_pesquisa.id_pesquisa = pc_pesquisa.id
WHERE pc_pesquisa.id_tipo = 1 ORDER BY pc_pesquisa.data ASC
```

Os dados das tabelas pc_pesquisa e usuarios retornam ok, porém só retorna as pesquisas que possuem respostas registradas. E preciso retornar mesmo qnd não há (null ou zero).

Atualmente possuo 2 pesquisas registradas, uma com 4 respostas e outra com 0 respostas. Esta query só retorna a pesquisa que tem respostas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, aparentemente precisava agrupar os resultados. A query ficou assim:

```
SELECT 
usuarios.nome AS nome_autor,
pc_pesquisa.*,
COUNT(pc_resposta_pesquisa.id) AS respostas 
FROM pc_pesquisa
    LEFT JOIN usuarios
        ON usuarios.id = pc_pesquisa.id_autor
    LEFT JOIN pc_resposta_pesquisa
        ON pc_resposta_pesquisa.id_pesquisa = pc_pesquisa.id
WHERE pc_pesquisa.id_tipo = 1 
    GROUP BY pc_pesquisa.id 
    ORDER BY pc_pesquisa.data ASC
```

Desta forma retorna mesmo quando há 0 respostas. N sei pq, mas funciona haha.
Então da pra fechar esta pergunta já que foi resolvido o problema.

Comment: Sempre que se usa funções de agregação em uma query é necessário especificar uma agregação. Por default o MySQL não faz essa validação mas nem por isso garante que a resposta é certa.